# whats wrong.. I cannot start apache2? using the comand : /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Tags: apache2

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 * 
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Comment: Did you read the log file? What does it say?

Answer (score 2):

```
Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

As the error states, then You already have a service listening to port 80. Try:

```
service apache2 restart
```

It could be apache thats already running, thus you can try restart it. If you still have problems, check your system for for other processes that might use port 80.